# SQL to select items not already in other table

Tags: sql-server

I currently have sql table (with its columns) as follows:

```
ORDERS (orderid, orderno, orderdate, customer)
ORDERDETAILS (id, orderid, itemcode, qty, price)

DELIVERY (deliveryid, orderid, deliverydate)
DELIVERYDETAILS (id, deliveryid, itemcode, qty)
```

ORDERS and ORDERDETAILS contains order of items. DELIVERY and DELIVERYDETAILS contains items that have been delivered, and it is 1 to Many to order (ie. 1 order can have many deliveries).

Example.

```
ORDERS: 1, '001', '2016-07-01', 'CUST001'
ORDERDETAILS:
1, 1, 'ITEM001', 1, 2.50
2, 1, 'ITEM002', 3, 7.50
3, 1, 'ITEM003', 6, 8.50

DELIVERY: 1, 1, '2016-07-02'
DELIVERY DETAILS:
1, 1, 'ITEM001', 1
2, 1, 'ITEM002', 1

DELIVERY: 2, 1, '2016-07-03'
DELIVERY DETAILS:
3, 2, 'ITEM002', 1
4, 2, 'ITEM003', 2
```

How do I need to generate a list of items that have not been delivered of an order using sql as follows.

```
UNDELIVERED ITEM as of '2016-07-04': itemcode, qty
'ITEM001', 0
'ITEM002', 1
'ITEM003', 4
```

Appreciate any advice.

Updates: Change order to orders. Added examples and results

Comment: How an order can have many deliveries ?. If a customer order 1 item it should be deliver to him only right ?

Comment: on a side note: it's considered bad practice (and it's just really inconvenient) to give your tables reserved keywords as names (in this case: ORDER)

Comment: @ArunCM orders are delivered many times, based on stock availability, yes, only to a customer.

Comment: @Jackie it's just a tip. Referencing tables or columns in square brackets becomes tedious after a short while :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that my understanding is correct. Because i am confused with order delivery relationship (ie. 1 to Many ). 
But according to my understanding you need list of all order no that doesn't have an delivery Id

```
SELECT o.orderid,o.orderno,o.customer
FROM ORDER o
LEFT JOIN DELIVERY d
ON o.orderno = d.orderno
WHERE d.orderno IS NULL
```

So this query will return all the `orderno` that is not in `delivery` table.
Are you expecting anything like this ?

**UPDATE** 
Query is may not optimized, But hope this will solve your issue.

```
SELECT dd.itemcode, SUM(dd.qty) as delivrdQty,
(SELECT od.qty FROM ORDERDETAILS od WHERE od.itemcode = dd.itemcode) as originalQty, 
(SELECT od.qty FROM ORDERDETAILS od WHERE od.itemcode = dd.itemcode) - SUM(dd.qty) as remainQty

FROM DELIVERYDETAILS dd 
INNER JOIN DELIVERY d ON dd.deliveryid = d.deliveryid
GROUP BY dd.itemcode ,dd.qty
```

Comment: this statement checks if order has delivery, but i need to check based on the items ordered and delivered, and which item(s) has or have not been delivered

Comment: @Jackie Please check the query and let me know if you face any issue. :)